# Pointer Declaration vs. Finite Array Declaration in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am experimenting with pointer and array declaration in C, and I am seeing results that do not make sense to me. Consider this function that converts binary to base 64:

```
char *bin2b64Str(char *binStr) {
    char finalb64str[256];
    char *paddedBin;
    int i, r, t, loops;
    char buffer[] = { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '\0' };

    int count = 0;
    r = 6 - strlen(binStr) % 6;
    if (r != 6) {
        loops = (int)strlen(binStr) / 6 + 1;
        paddedBin = (char*)malloc(((strlen(binStr) + r) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        memmove(paddedBin, &buffer[6 - r], r);
        memmove(&paddedBin[r], binStr, strlen(binStr) + 1);
    }else{
        loops = (int) strlen(binStr) / 6;
        paddedBin = (char*)malloc(((strlen(binStr)) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        memmove(paddedBin, binStr, strlen(binStr) + 1);
    }

    char b64str[strlen(binStr) + r + 1];
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        char sextet[7];
        ++count;
        if (count != loops) {
            memcpy(sextet, &paddedBin[6 * i], 6);
            sextet[6] = '\0';
        } else {
            memcpy(sextet, &paddedBin[6 * i], 7);
            sextet[6] = '\0';
        }
        b64str[i] = bin2b64Char(sextet);
    }
    memcpy(finalb64str, b64str, loops);
    finalb64str[loops] = '\0';

    return finalb64str;
}
```

This code works just fine for me, but if I instead change the first line to:

```
char *finalb64str
```

and replace the last memcpy line with:

```
finalb64str = b64str;
```

it fails miserably! I don't understand at all.  Why is this happening? I have been researching all about pointers and arrays, but nothing I've found seems to answer this for me.

Comment: Why are you casting the return value from `malloc`?

Comment: @Matt it is both invalid: The lifetime of the storage for the arrays ends with the return of the function. Make the array static, return `malloc()`ed space or fill a buffer given by the caller.

Comment: Using `strlen()` on binary data is dubious; it will stop counting at the first null byte, but binary data may have null bytes at any point.

Answer (score 0):

```
char b64str[strlen(binStr)+r + 1];
```

is an array allocated on the stack which is local to the function, any references to it when the function has returned are invalid.

when you write

```
finalb64str = b64str;
```

at the end you are just assigning the local variable to the array that is declared locally, the address returned will be invalid.

in order to make b64str visible on the outside it easiest if you malloc the storage and then return the pointer to that.

```
char* b64str = malloc(strlen(binStr)+r + 1);
...
return b64str;
```